# Getting comma separated output while converting feature importance into a dataframe. How to avoid that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

My code is below

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': X_xgb, 'Feature importance': xgb.feature_importances_})
```

I am trying to convert the feature importances in a dataframe. However, the names of the features in 'tmp' dataframe are comma separated characters like below.

```
  Feature   Feature importance
0   (c, u, s, t, o, m, _, w, i, n, _, p, r, o, b, ...   0.138277
29  (q, u, o, t, e, _, t, e, a, m, _, c, _, 3, 4)   0.108177
36  (q, u, o, t, e, _, t, e, a, m, _, c, _, 5, 3)   0.089881
88  (e, n, t, i, t, y, _, c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y, ...   0.075270
27  (q, u, o, t, e, _, t, e, a, m, _, c, _, 3, 1)   0.062880
14  (q, u, o, t, e, _, b, u, s, i, n, e, s, s, _, ...   0.057267
```

I have two questions:
1. Why the feature names get stored like that?
2. How to avoid comma separated output for this?
The data in X_xgb contains the features that look like below

```
X_xgb
'custom_win_probability'
'quote_team_c_34'
'entity_category'
```

xgb refers to XGBoost classifier which is used as below.

```
xgb= XGBClassifier(silent=0,n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: can you provide more data, i.e  reproducible samples for **X_xgb** and **xgb**?

Comment: Hi @Snehil, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for edting, can you add what is the datatype of **X_xgb**, as if it was series or dataframe, then it is a strange behaviour!

Comment: It's a dataframe.